# datepart in sql on year change

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using datepart function in SP. It is used to compare week and year of specified date.

Now my query arise as new year starts. I have one table called 'Task' and it is storing tasks date wise. Now When I execute SP with `DATEPART(YY,'2016-01-05')` . It is giving proper 2016's data. But I execute it with `DATEPART(ISOWK,'2016-01-05')` , it is giving 2015's data also with 2016's data.

I want data from 28th dec,2015 to 2nd jan,2016. Data of the week. And I am not able get data of 1st and 2nd Jan in that. Please help me with this.

Thanks,

Comment: please show the SP that you have created

Comment: Why can't you use date>= 2015-12-28 AND date=<2016-01-02

Comment: you said "DATEPART(ISOWK,'2016-01-05') , it is giving 2015's data also with 2016's data. ". you also said "I am not able get data of 1st and 2nd " ..... contradiction please clarify??

Comment: I don't think it's very clear what you're asking - but a simple heuristic for dealing with the year end is that if the week number is > 30 and the month is January, subtract one from the year.

Answer (score 0):

ISOWK return the week number

You are trying to get date from 2015-12-28 to 2016-01-02. 
The week number of 2015-12-28 is 53 and 2016-01-02 is 53

Answer (score 0):

If you already have your start and end dates decided then you could use a simple query as shown below to filter on date range.

When mentioning date string in your query make sure you stick to this format :`yyyymmdd` which SQL Server will automatically understand. You don't need `DATEPART` to get records between two dates.

**Query for filtering on a date range**

```
SELECT TaskID, TaskDescription
 FROM  Tasks 
where TaskDate between '20151228' and '20160102'
```

**Another query you can use for date range filtering**

```
SELECT TaskID, TaskDescription
 FROM  Tasks 
where TaskDate >= '20151228' and TaskDate <= '20160102'
```